# Control Radio Controlled boat from Android?

Tags: bluetooth, remote-control

[Cross posted on robotics.stackexchange]

TL;DR: I'm looking for a RF transmitter than I can control from an android app. Does such hardware exist? I can't find it but it seems like something would be used for communicating with long range drones.

Here's some more detail:

We're working on a project to convert a radio controlled Sailboat to be controlled by an  app. We've considered different kinds of communication methods and have concluded that the best way is to stay with radio frequency, which is what most of the remote controlled boats use.

There's a RF receiver on the boat. There was also originally a standard RF transmitter (see pic below) but we'd like to replace that with an app. Standard phones don't have the capability to transmit on the right frequency, so I'm wondering if there's some device which the app communicates with over a standard radio (e.g., Bluetooth) and that device sends out RF to the boat.

[image: Example of current and proposed approach]

This approach is appealing because the boat hardware will work largely as is.

Comment: This is off-topic `Questions asking the community to find or recommend something for you (a device, app, ROM, website, etc), including what to buy and where to buy it`

Comment: I’m not asking for a particular recommendation. I’m asking if the class of this device exists. 

Does such a thing exist? And if not, how do people meet the need I expressed?